# Optical flow by Lucas-Kanade method?

Tags: python, opencv, opticalflow

The method given in OpenCV tutorials-python has some delay in processing,it is like playing the video at 0.5 speed, Can you suggest any other method where in the optical flow feature(displacement vector fields) can be obtained with a negligible delay?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("vtest.avi")

ret, frame1 = cap.read()
prvs = cv2.cvtColor(frame1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
hsv = np.zeros_like(frame1)
hsv[...,1] = 255

while(1):
    ret, frame2 = cap.read()
    next = cv2.cvtColor(frame2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prvs,next, None, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0)

    mag, ang = cv2.cartToPolar(flow[...,0], flow[...,1])
    hsv[...,0] = ang*180/np.pi/2
    hsv[...,2] = cv2.normalize(mag,None,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(hsv,cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

    cv2.imshow('frame2',rgb)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
    elif k == ord('s'):
        cv2.imwrite('opticalfb.png',frame2)
        cv2.imwrite('opticalhsv.png',rgb)
    prvs = next

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: `k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff` should help

Comment: @Miki I am not sure that it will help in his case, maybe only a little bit. The main consumer here is probably the Farneback optical flow calculation.

Comment: @A.Sarid I said _help_, not _solve the problem_ ;D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the method you are using in your code is **not** Lucas-Kanade. You are using `calcOpticalFlowFarneback` function which is the [Farneback](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:273847/FULLTEXT01.pdf) method for motion estimation.

In general, optical flow is quite a heavy algorithm, and it really depends on your needs.  You have mainly two types of methods - sparse and dense:

- [`calcOpticalFlowFarneback`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga5d10ebbd59fe09c5f650289ec0ece5af)
  is a dense algorithm, which means that it generates a flow matrix as
  the size of your frame, it actually calculates the flow for every
  pixel.
- [`calcOpticalFlowPyrLK`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga473e4b886d0bcc6b65831eb88ed93323)
  (Lucas-Kanade) method is a sparse method that takes only specified
  number of pixels and calculates the flow on them.

You might want to try Lucas-Kanade method if you want better performance.
Take a look at this [OpenCV Optical Flow Tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_lucas_kanade.html#gsc.tab=0), you have there both examples for Farneback and Lucas-Kanade.

In the Lucas-Kanade example they are using the [`goodFeaturesToTrack`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga1d6bb77486c8f92d79c8793ad995d541) method which generates number of pixels that are good to track in such motion estimation algorithms. Depends on what your needs are, you might want to use this method or define some pixels yourself.
Note that you can of course change the number of processed pixels and by that change the processing time of the algorithm.

You might want to checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309567/speeding-up-optical-flow-createoptflow-dualtvl1) as well, even though it is for DualTVL1 method, it might also apply to other methods.

Comment: ThankYou @A. Sarid "goodFeaturesToTrack" was pretty fast ... served the purpose